# Destructure immutable reference and bind mutably in parameter list

Tags: rust

I want to destructure a reference to a `Copy`-type and bind the resulting value mutably. *Note*: yes, I want to create a copy of the given argument and mutate that copy. This works:

```
fn foo(a: &u64) {
    let mut a = *a;
    mutate(&mut a);
}
```

But I want to do it via destructuring in the argument list. When I just destructure like this:

```
fn foo(&a: &u64) {
    mutate(&mut a);
}
```

Rust (understandably) complains:

```
<anon>:3:17: 3:18 error: cannot borrow immutable local variable `a` as mutable
<anon>:3     mutate(&mut a);
                         ^
<anon>:1:9: 1:10 help: to make the local variable mutable, use `mut` as shown:
<anon>:  fn foo(&mut a: &u64) {
```

But the solution the compiler suggests does not work!

```
<anon>:1:8: 1:14 error: mismatched types:
 expected `&u64`,
    found `&mut _`
(values differ in mutability) [E0308]
<anon>:1 fn foo(&mut a: &u64) {
                ^~~~~~
```

How to do what I want?

Comment: It really feels like `fn foo(mut &a: &u64)` should work, but it doesn't.

Comment: @Shepmaster Why should it work? `mut` applies to *names*, not whole patterns. You're not making the reference mutable, you're making `a` mutable.

Comment: @delnan I'll admit to not thoroughly thinking through all the potential avenues. Maybe it's bad-ole-C-thinking - destructure with `&` and then make the result mutable. That's why I made a comment instead of really showing my ignorance in an answer ^_^.

Comment: I don't think this is possible. You are using a Copy type in this case so you could just take `mut a: u64` instead of a reference. Then, any time the function is called the compiler generates a mutable copy for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. While patterns can destructure data (i.e., introduce bindings for parts of data), and bindings can be marked mutable, there doesn't seem to be a way to combine the two in the case of destructuring a reference, even though other combinations work:

```
struct X(i32);
let it = X(5);
let X(mut inside) = it;
inside = 1;
```

This may just be an edge case where other syntactic choices leave no good possibility. As you noticed, `&mut x` is already taken, and disambiguating with parentheses is not supported in patterns.

This isn't a big issue because there are several ways to do the same thing outside the pattern:

1. Don't make the binding mutable in the pattern and then make a new, mutable binding (`let mut x = x;`)
2. Don't destructure to begin with ‐ it's not terribly useful with references since you can just say `let mut x = *reference;`.

Trying to be too clever in argument lists is detrimental to readability anyway IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work on the Rust playground:

```
fn foo(mut a: &mut u64) {
    mutate(a);
}
```

Short answer is that you need to take in a mutable parameter that has the type of a mutable reference to a `u64`. I cannot provide a better answer, I'm still learning.

Here you can see a working example: [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9ba6d56f9633e3ae8b89773121880ecd&version=stable&backtrace=0)

I am not 100% sure if I understand what you're asking, but it's worth a shot.

Comment: In your code the type of `a` is different (`&mut u64` vs `&u64`).

Comment: That's true, but it is one solution to the problem. Because I'm not sure if they want a mutable reference or a mutable value.

Comment: The question has since been clarified.